# Retrieve records between given a value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Please can you give any idea of how retrieve records given a particular value in a column.

For example. I have a table with several columns, one of them is "Bill Cycle". For each record in that table, the column "Bill Cycle" only have the values "01", "09", "16" or "23".

So, i want to apply a rule such that:

If column "Bill Cycle" has the value "01", extract records from 01-01-2019 to 31-01-2019.

If column "Bill Cycle" has the value "09", extract records from 09-01-2018 to 08-02-2019.

If column "Bill Cycle" has the value "16", extract records from 16-01-2019 to 15-02-2019.

If column "Bill Cycle" has the value "23", extract records from 23-12-2018 to 23-01-2019.

Comment: Looks like you want the most recent (started) 30 day period, with YY as start day? Do you want 23-01-2019 to 23-02-2019 tomorrow for "23"?

Comment: Yes, 30 days períod (dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
where (bill_cycle = '01' and datecol >= date '2019-01-01' and datecol < date '2019-01-31') or
      (bill_cycle = '09' and datecol >= date '2018-01-09' and datecol < date '2019-02-08') or
      (bill_cycle = '16' and datecol >= date '2019-01-16' and datecol < date '2019-02-15') or
      (bill_cycle = '23' and datecol >= date '2019-12-23' and datecol < date '2019-01-23')
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want a dynamic solution, because i will run this code every month, and do not want to change the dates manually...

Comment: @PauloSilva . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question and be clear about the logic you want to implement. It is rude to change a question in such a way that answers are invalidated, because that can attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your WHERE clause like so:

```
WHERE
(bill_cycle = '01' and dt_column between to_date('01-01-2019,'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('31-01-2019,'dd-mm-yyyy'))
OR
(bill_cycle = '09' and dt_column between to_date('09-01-2018,'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('08-02-2019,'dd-mm-yyyy')) 
OR
etc. etc.
```